# Proving $x^n=y$ has 2 solutions if n even natural and $y>0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Hi how is my proof for the question with $n$ an even natural number and $y>0$ $x^n=y$ has two solutions.

Assume n is some even natural number and $y>0$. The equation $x^n=y$ has one $x>0$ which satisfies it by the existence of roots.

Also $x^n=(-x)^n$ for all $x$. Therefore

$x^n=y$ if and only if $(-x)^n=y$

Thanks

Comment: The last part is fine. What exactly do you mean by existence of roots? x^2+1 has no root in $\mathbb{R}$, so what about the equation in question are you using?

Comment: You mean real-valued solutions?

Comment: Thanks I meant to say that I'm assuming the existence of a unique x>0 which satisfies x^n=y and I can do this because of an assumption about nth roots

Comment: Yes real valued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof needs a little touching-up in some places:

- You say there is one $x>0$ such that $x^n=y$. You also need to say this $x$ is *unique*, so that the desired conclusion can be reached.
- After showing $x^n=y\iff(-x)^n=y$, you need to state that since there is a unique *positive* $x$ satisfying the original equation, this "reflection identity" means there is also a unique *negative* $x$ satisfying it.
- The case of $x=0$ should also be dealt with, but that is easy. Combining positive, negative and zero $x$, you may conclude the desired result.